# How do I write a function that takes in two different image arrays, plots the "difference image," and returns the difference image array?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, fits

So I have these 2 images I downloaded from a fits file. Here is the code located below. Now I want to create a function that takes in both those image arrays and subtracts each array from eachother and then plots the difference as a new picture. Can anyone help me out? I'm really stuck on it been working at it for 4 hours to no avail.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits

Image_file = fits.open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msu-cmse-courses/cmse202-S21-student/master/data/m42_40min_ir.fits')

fourty_min_ir = Image_file[0].data
type(fourty_min_ir)

Image_file = fits.open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msu-cmse-courses/cmse202-S21-student/master/data/m42_40min_red.fits')

fourty_min_red = Image_file[0].data
type(fourty_min_red)
```

Comment: what is the difference image doing?  is it subtracting one image from another

Comment: Yeah its subtracting the red image - the IR image

Comment: plt.imshow(fourty_min_red)
plt.show() .    I see two images.  the resulting image will be ir mask

Comment: https://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2010/10/22/making-rgb-images-from-fits-files-with-pythonmatplotlib/  (see converting fits file to r g b)

Comment: they use pyfits to combine the r g b fits files together.

Answer (score 1):

```
results_img=fourty_min_ir-fourty_min_red

plt.imshow(results_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much that worked perfectly... Didn't realize it was so simple haha

Comment: I did vote but theres a rule that votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score :) cheerio